# base64 string changed to [removed]

Tags: php, jquery

Im submitting a base64 data thru ajax post.

> data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQS...

is changed to

> [removed]/9j/4AAQS...

when submitted.

Comment: trun off XSS clean on server side script

Comment: my post is not set to TRUE but still getting that result